# Volume too loud

Tags: audio, windows-10

I am on volume 2 on my computer, rarely do I have to go above 10. This is too loud, going from 2 to 4 is too drastic of a change.

**Can I lower the volume by a factor of 10 or such?**

Comment: What physical speakers do you have and do they have volume controls?  It sounded like your physical speakers are turned up high.

Comment: Bose quietcomfort 25 with noise canceling on

Answer (score 0):

The level is too "hot". Are there other jacks you could try?  A line-out vs. speaker-out, for example.

A "flex jack" might have different modes, and you can configure it for headphones.

If all else fails, this level matching is a common problem for pro audio (and hobby use mixing semi-pro and consumer equipment), and you can buy high-quality "pads" that plug in-line to cut the volume.  There are compex conditioning devices that can be adjusted and fill several roles, but since this is a perminant known use that would be overkill.

I have inexpensive powered speakers that have a headphone jack, and the volume knob works on the headphones when plugged in. Using that, instead of plugging directly into the line-out, would solve your problem too.

The Sound Design SE has discussions on level matching and the general mess of plugging audio devices together.